# Return value of cell based on other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to fill different data in one column and link it with the data filled in a different column. For example: I want to use "animal, bird, reptiles" in the cells of e.g., column `A` and I want to fill the total no., e.g., 11, 14, and 33 in column `B`. The range of the data in the two columns is the same (i.e., same number of rows). Thus, when I select animal, the second column should return value 11, and, when I select bird, it should return value 14.

Comment: "when i select animal 2nd column" - how would you be selecting the 2nd animal from the column?

Comment: Where does the number 11, 14  or 33 come from? Is it a fixed value somewhere or is it actually totalling something up? It sounds like you need a simple lookup or index/match, or possibly a SUMIF or COUNTIF but your question is unclear about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1:** Consider drop down lists

In cells (e.g., `A1`, `A2`, `A3`), put the list of values (animal, bird, reptiles) and then in a cell (e.g., some other column `B1`), use these values to make a drop down list. In the next cell (`C1`), use a formula to get the value for the selected element:

`C1 = calculate total of item in B1`

Check out: [Link 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b), [Link 2](https://spreadsheeto.com/drop-down/), [Link 3](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list-in-excel/), [Link 4](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/drop-down-list.html)

---

**SOLUTION 2:** Alternatively, consider data filtering

You have to make two columns with the headers, the names, and the numbers. Here is the example:

`A1=CreatureName, A2=animal, A3=bird, A4=reptiles`

`B1=TotalNumber, B2=11, B3=14, B4=33`

Now select the header row & select data filter. Here, the formula is not necessary and you can have a column with the numbers.

Check out: [Link 5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-7fbe34f4-8382-431d-942e-41e9a88f6a96), [Link 6](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2010/filtering-data/1/), [Link 7](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_data_analysis/excel_data_analysis_filtering.htm), [Link 8](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/filter.html)

---

**SOLUTION 3:** You get more granular control with VBA Macros, which will entail more effort. Not advisable at this Point.